# Is adding a parallel word that only intersects the end letter of an existing word allowed in Scrabble?

Tags: scrabble

I won a game by getting lots of points doing it ;)
but was contested and I could see their point.

Here are two examples:

```
PLACES
     OTHER
```

or

```
    BRILLIANT
SCORE
```

I can see from the official rules something similar is allowed:

```
 PASTE
BIT
```

The difference here is that BIT, PI and AT are created. So there is more than one parallel word created.

But are the examples I give only one parallel word is created, is this ok?

Comment: Sounds like you were playing with some noobies. This is pretty basic Scrabble strategy. There's a great documentary about high-level Scrabble play called Word Wars if you're interested in learning more about the game.

Comment: I just watched the trailer... I think I'm going to have to see this now ;)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The play you describe is both legal and generally easier to do than the multi-cross play you cite as a rules example.

The general rules relevant here are that, first, all the letters for a single play must be in a single line, either vertical or horizontal, and second, that all tiles adjacent to another tile (vertically or horizontally) must be part of a permissible words in each direction of adjacency.  Finally, at least one tile of any new play must be adjacent to a tile already played (except the first play of a new game, for which one tile must be on the pink star center square).

Comment: If BRILLIANT has been played, can a player put the letter E under B, and O under T, and no other letters? That satisfies all the conditions you set out.

Comment: @Acccumulation no, the tiles you play must form a single word.