# Scrabble - Parallel Words joined at one letter

Tags: scrabble, scoring

## Parallel words joined at a single letter forming a second word.

I cannot seem to find a clear answer to this scrabble question.

Say player one plays, "scrabble" as their first word.
Is it valid for player two to then play, "hello," parallel to "scrabble" but starting with the "h" in "hello" next to the "e" in "scrabble" to make the second word, "he." Here is an example:

```
       HELLO
SCRABBLE
```

Comment: Yes. That's perfectly fine. Note that while 'scrabble' could *a player's* first word, it could not be *the* first word

Comment: Are you kidding??? My wife has _memorized_ a list of all the 2-letter words she can find (and she's spent _years_ updating her list) just so she can make plays like this!

Comment: @FreeMan - The Official Scrabble Dictionary has a list of all two letter words, among other lists; be interesting to see if her list has some they missed!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is adding a parallel word that only intersects the end letter of an existing word allowed in Scrabble?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/is-adding-a-parallel-word-that-only-intersects-the-end-letter-of-an-existing-wor)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [official rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) state:

New words may be formed by:

- Adding one or more letters to a word or letters already on the board.
- Placing a word at right angles to a word already on the board. The new word must use
  one of the letters already on the board or must add a letter to it.
- Placing a complete word parallel to a word already played so that adjacent letters also form complete words.

And in the scoring examples, the last example shows a similar case to yours - the word BIT is played underneath PASTE as such:

```
  P A S T E
B I T
```

with the player scoring for the words BIT, PI and AT which are formed from the running parallel words. So yes, your example is valid - it is a single word, played parallel to an existing word, such that all adjacent tiles result in forming valid English words.

Comment: The only requirement is that all letters you place must be in the same row or column with no spaces between them, and all strings of adjacent letters must form valid words.  Doing words parallel to existing words often scores much better than perpendicular words (since each letter is counted twice), which is the reason why all serious Scrabble players should learn and memorize the complete list of valid 2-letter words.

Comment: Isn't that "PASTE / BIT" example from the box lid (a long time ago)? :)

Comment: It probably is, because I don't think they changed the rules much when they put them online.